# Fragment inside ViewPager inside ViewGroup

Tags: android, android-fragments, view, android-viewpager, viewgroup

**Problem**

As shown in the figure below, I have two tabs called "température" which are created in the same way (see mainFragment). In this two tabs, I have a viewpager to get previous graphics ( 05 august, 04 august,...).
The first tab works well but in the second, nothing appears. When debugging, I can see that the fragment is created in both cases. It's only on the second tab where the problem is. Even more, I can see the viewpager working when sliding to the left or right end.
I'm seeking since hours now and I don't understand where the problem is. Why the fragments don't appear ?
I'm using android.support.v13.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter for the adapter.

Here is a short movie to show the problem :
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vf8qlrd75mdwijp/device-2017-08-06-214510.mp4?dl=0

[image]

**Code**

**MainFragment**

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements BTListener {


// the different ID for the views.
private final static int ID_TEMPERATURE = 1;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main,container,false);

    final ViewGroup mainContainer = (ViewGroup) rootView.findViewById(R.id.main_container);

    createTemperatureTab(mainContainer);
    createTemperatureTab(mainContainer);

    return rootView;
}

private void createTemperatureTab(ViewGroup mainContainer){

    //inflate the view
    ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.main_list,mainContainer,false);
    ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title_main_list)).setText("Température");
    ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.information_main_list)).setText("°C");
    final ExpandableLayout expandableLayout = (ExpandableLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.expandable_layout);

    CustomPager viewPager = (CustomPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    LinearGraphAdapter linearGraphAdapter = new LinearGraphAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(linearGraphAdapter);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(linearGraphAdapter.getCount());

    expandableLayout.setExpanded(false);
    expandableLayout.setDuration(500);
    expandableLayout.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());

    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(expandableLayout.isExpanded()) {
                expandableLayout.collapse();
            }
            else {
                expandableLayout.expand();
            }
        }
    });
    mainContainer.addView(view);
}

}
```

**main_list**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_main_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/information_main_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<net.cachapa.expandablelayout.ExpandableLayout
    android:id="@+id/expandable_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <com.example.renaud.aquariumslinding.adapter.CustomPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </com.example.renaud.aquariumslinding.adapter.CustomPager>

</net.cachapa.expandablelayout.ExpandableLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

**LineGraphFragment**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.linear_graph_layout,container,false);

    lineChart = (LineChart) rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_graph);
    initiateChart(lineChart); // not important for this case
    drawChart(lineChart,dayOfYear); // not important for this case

    return rootView;
}
```

**linear_graph_layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/linear_graph_date"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:textColor="#fff" />
<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
    android:id="@+id/linear_graph"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**LinearGraphAdapter**

```
public class LinearGraphAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

public static int MAXIMUM_COUNT_PAGER = 7;
private int mCurrentPosition = -1;

public LinearGraphAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager){
    super(fragmentManager);
}
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt(Constant.CUSTOM_PAGER_NUMBER,MAXIMUM_COUNT_PAGER-position);
    Fragment fragment = new LinearGraphFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);

    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return MAXIMUM_COUNT_PAGER;
}

@Override
public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, object);
    if (position != mCurrentPosition) {
        Fragment fragment = (Fragment) object;
        CustomPager pager = (CustomPager) container;
        if (fragment != null && fragment.getView() != null) {
            mCurrentPosition = position;
            pager.measureCurrentView(fragment.getView());
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried logging to see if the fragments are measured correctly? What about checking the layout bounds to see if your views are actually visible, given that  your expandable layout starts off as collapsed. In regards to your null check under setPrimaryItem, I'm not sure why it's there. If you expect it to be null, you'll likely need to handle it if it is. If you don't expect it to be null, have a look to see if there's ever a case where it is. Your layouts heights are also all wrap_content so if no data is given nothing will be visible

Comment: Fragments of both expandable layouts are the same size, well measured.
If I check the layout bounds, we can see they well appear : http://hpics.li/f7f188c
Finally, in the function setPrimaryItem, I just copied a code from internet. After looking in it, it seems that it is called two times. The second time, it is a null element. I had to check that more deeply, but it's not part of the solution.
Indeed, as you mention, if I change wrap_content to 150dp, and comment the "setPrimaryItem" function, the problem remains the same ( see http://hpics.li/5afaec3).
Thx for your great help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a night of research and reading the API I figured it out. I don't understand everything but it seems the v13 and v4 library have a conflict.

To override it, firstly :

- Make sure that you called getChildFragmentManager() instead of getFragmentManager()
- Create a different ID for all the different viewpageryou have. Those IDs must have at least 4 digits. Of course, it is better to have those in R.String
- Set your ID in every viewpager by calling setID()
- If it doesn't work, please clean and rebuild your project.

And finally, the reward :

[image]

I hope that it will help.